# Create a hide show element based on conditional in fuse tools

Tags: fusetools

I would like to create a left menu in [fuse tools](http://fusetools.com) that would allow for a conditional based on the devices width. This should show the menu on an ipad or tablet device and hide it on a mobile device.

Just wondering if anyone knows how to do this. I cant seem to find any documentation on it, but can imagine it to be something like

```
<StackPanel ShowWhenDeviceWidth="960">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [WhileWindowSize](https://www.fusetools.com/docs/fuse/triggers/whilewindowsize) trigger to dynamically include content based on the size of the device (the window on a device is the full screen size).

You need to always specify both an X and Y value. Your setup may look like this:

```
<WhileWindowSize GreaterThan="959,1">
   <StackPanel>
       ....
   </StackPanel>
</WhileWindowSize>
```